# Google Script next cell in column

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Been scouring the internet but not found a solution

Basically I am wanting to paste data in the next available row in a specific column.

The column i want to paste into is H

Example - Cell H1 and H2 has data inside it - so i need the code to paste the values in H3 (next available cell)

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73777592/how-to-access-the-cell-next-to-the-selected-cell-in-google-sheet-using-script is probably the shortest way

Answer (score 3):

got it working in the end..
For those of you interested my code is below

```
function putInNextAvaibleRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('Test');     //Rename to your sheet
  var row=1;                               //start row to loop through
  var col=8;                               //column you want to loop through
  var value=34567;                         //value you want to assign - can be a cell or anything
  while(sht.getRange(row,col).getValue()!=""){
    row++;
  }

  sht.getRange(row,col).setValue(value);
  Browser.msgBox("Sheet is "+row+".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access user's clipboard, Google drive API don't give this possiblity.
But, you can put data in the next available row in a specific column.
Here's the solution :

```
function putInNextAvaibleRow(sheet,col,value) {
  var row=1;
  while(sheet.getRange(row,col).getValue()!=""){
    row++;
  }
  sheet.getRange(row,col).setValue(value);
}
```

Comment: sorry should have explained in a bit more detail - i will be copying cell c6:c8 on the same sheet to the next available row in column H (No need for clip board)

Comment: Ok, then, you could use the function I just wrote for you. The parameter col will be 8 (H is 8th letter) and the parameter value will be  the value of the cell you want to copy.

Comment: sorry really new to this, can't seem to get it working, this will be used within a larger script - essentially I am copying data automatically from cells c6:cxx (xx been a variable number) to the next available row in column H

Comment: What is your question ?