# Move value to the next available blank cell in column via checkbox in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to be able to move a cell value from one worksheet to another using a checkbox and want the cell to move to the next available cell in column B.

I'm able to move rows from one worksheet to another using a checkbox using the code below but the row appends to the end of the worksheet rather than to the next blank cell in col B.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
function onEdit(e){
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (r.rowStart == 1 || r.columnStart != 1) return;
  let dest;
  if (src.getName() == "Sheet1")
    dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  else if (src.getName() == "Sheet2")
    dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");  
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,1).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,1));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
}
```

Comment: try using Range.offset(0,1)

Answer (score 0):

**Recommendation:**

Aside from adding **[offset(0,1)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer))** on `.moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,1).offset(0,1))` as advised from the previous comment, you can also tweak the destination sheet range of your moveTo() function:

**from** `.moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,1));`
**to**`.moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,2,1,2));`

To place the cell value to an empty available cell on Column B (column 2) on the other worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer I was looking for here:

[Google Script next cell in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354118/google-script-next-cell-in-column)