# How to access the cell next to the selected cell in Google sheet using script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I just started exploring google sheets and JavaScript and I wrote a function which prompts the user to type a string which is entered into the selected cell. I'm accessing the current cell using `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell()` and setting the value using `.setValue()`.

Now I made another prompt and I want to put this value in the cell next to the selected cell (same row but column+1). How do I access the current cells row and column positions and then increment the col with 1?

In pseudo code I'm thinking something like this:

```
ActiveCell[row][column+1] = string input from prompt2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`offset`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset) to specify offset:

```
let cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();

// update cell to the right
cell.offset(0, 1).setValue("upd");
```

Comment: This is so much more simple than looking at the event range in `onEdit(e)` override. I don't know why it was so difficult!